# WebLogic 12c cluster deploying error

Tags: log4j, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm trying to deploy an EAR to a clustered weblogic 12c environment.

To configure log4j, i followed [this](http://danielveselka.blogspot.hu/2012/08/configure-slf4j-with-log4j-on-weblogic.html) post, but when i try to deploy, I get an exception:

```
An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.
Message icon - Error Exception activating module: EJBModule(kvbejb3app-ejb.jar) Unable to deploy EJB: /opt/oracle/product/Middleware/domains/test_domain/servers/server1/tmp/_WL_user/kvbejb3app/a9h58b/kvbejb3app-ejb.jar from kvbejb3app-ejb.jar: Unable to deploy EJB: /opt/oracle/product/Middleware/domains/test_domain/servers/server1/tmp/_WL_user/kvbejb3app/a9h58b/kvbejb3app-ejb.jar from kvbejb3app-ejb.jar:
Message icon - Error http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage
Message icon - Success The deployment has been successfully installed.
```

Stacktrace:

```
Unable to deploy EJB: /opt/oracle/product/Middleware/domains/test_domain/servers/server2/tmp/_WL_user/kvbejb3app/84mgd8/kvbejb3app-ejb.jar from kvbejb3app-ejb.jar:

    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.activate(EJBModule.java:479)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.activate(ScopedModuleDriver.java:206)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.activate(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:97)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.activate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.activate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:145)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:582)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:335)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setAttribute(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:118)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.server.DefaultContainerBootstrap.bootstrap(DefaultContainerBootstrap.java:51)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.server.Bootstrap.deploy(Bootstrap.java:147)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.WLSBootstrap.deploy(WLSBootstrap.java:108)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.server.Bootstrap.deploy(Bootstrap.java:114)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.BaseComponentBrokerImpl.initialize(BaseComponentBrokerImpl.java:45)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.EjbComponentCreatorBrokerImpl.initialize(EjbComponentCreatorBrokerImpl.java:43)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EjbComponentCreatorImpl.initialize(EjbComponentCreatorImpl.java:65)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.initializeComponentCreator(EJBDeployer.java:721)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.activate(EJBDeployer.java:942)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.activate(EJBModule.java:470)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.activate(ScopedModuleDriver.java:206)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.activate(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:97)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.activate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.activate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:145)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:582)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:335)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
>
```

weblogic.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" 
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd 
                        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app 
                        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <weblogic-version>12.1.1</weblogic-version>
    <session-descriptor>
        <timeout-secs>300</timeout-secs>
        <invalidation-interval-secs>60</invalidation-interval-secs>
        <persistent-store-type>replicated_if_clustered</persistent-store-type>
    </session-descriptor> 
    <jsp-descriptor>
        <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
        <debug>true</debug>
    </jsp-descriptor>
    <context-root>/kvbejb3app-war</context-root>
    <container-descriptor>     
        <!-- <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>  -->
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>org.slf4j</package-name>
            </prefer-application-packages>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

weblogic-appplication.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application" 
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd 
                            http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application 
                            http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.4/weblogic-application.xsd">

    <application-param>
        <param-name>webapp.encoding.default</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </application-param>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.slf4j</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

The exception don't tell me anything.. what did I miss?

Comment: The error you want to research is the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage`. Check the following post: https://www.java.net//node/676936

Comment: I've searched for the 'http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage' string in the project, but the result was empty.
I think the problem is in the attached XML files, because before I edited them, the deployment was fine.

Comment: Can you update your weblogic-application.xml file? I see it references Java EE 5 XSD at java.sun.com. Perhaps you want to update to the Java EE 6 version, since 12c is certified on it?